# Error to retrieve the data from the play console with python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-play-console, playback

I try to have the google play console data-report into a pandas dataframe.

```
# set up the data
import datetime

monday = str(datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7))

sunday = str(datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1))


import pandas as pd
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# Set your credentials file path

credentials_file = "authentification.json"


# Set the package name of your app
package_name = 'my_package-name'

# Set the desired start and end dates for the data report (already set)


# Build the service using your credentials
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
   credentials_file, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher']
)
service = build('androidpublisher', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

# Retrieve the data report
response = service.reviews().list(
   packageName=package_name,
   maxResults=1000,
   startDate=monday,
   endDate=sunday
).execute()

# Extract the review data from the response
reviews = response['reviews']

# Convert the review data to a Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(reviews)

# Print the DataFrame
print(df.head())
```

But I have this error:

```
MalformedError: Service account info was not in the expected format, missing fields token_uri, client_email.
```

How can I resolve this error?

I try to use this block to bypass this issue:

```
import google.auth
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('authentification.json')
scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'])
```

But I have the same issue.

Comment: Does your json file include those fields.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan yes i have those fields include in my JSON